# PySpark - Dataframe column data type validation returns error though data type length assigned is correct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Dataframe is having 3 columns

1. id - int
2. emp_sal - input is string, data type need to consider as decimal(17,2) for validation
3. avg_sal - input is string, data type need to consider as decimal(19,6) for validation

PySpark Code for data type validation

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
   [
       (1,"999999999999999.99","0"),
       (2,"999999999999999.99","0")
   ],
   ["id", "emp_sal","avg_sal"]  # add your column names here
)

dd_file_col_type = {}
(dd_key,dd_val) = ("id",lambda c: f.col(c).cast("int"))
dd_file_col_type[dd_key] = dd_val

v_dec_prec='17'
v_dec_scale='2'
v_dec_fun1='decimal('+v_dec_prec+','+v_dec_scale+')'
print(v_dec_fun1)
(dd_key,dd_val) = ("emp_sal",lambda c: f.col(c).cast(v_dec_fun1))
dd_file_col_type[dd_key] = dd_val

v_dec_prec='19'
v_dec_scale='6'
v_dec_fun1='decimal('+v_dec_prec+','+v_dec_scale+')'
print(v_dec_fun1)
(dd_key,dd_val) = ("avg_sal",lambda c: f.col(c).cast(v_dec_fun1))
dd_file_col_type[dd_key] = dd_val

df_data_valid=df2.withColumn(
       "Errors",
       f.concat_ws("| ",
           *[
               f.when(v(k).isNull() & f.col(k).isNotNull() & f.when(f.col(k) =='',False).otherwise(True),
               f.concat(f.lit("ERROR: Column " + k +  " value not valid : "),f.col(k))
               ).otherwise(f.lit(None))
               for k, v in dd_file_col_type.items()
           ]
           )
       )
df_data_valid.show(truncate=False)
```

--Output

| id | emp_sal | avg_sal | Errors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 999999999999999.99 | 0 | ERROR: Column emp_sal value not valid : 999999999999999.99 |
| 2 | 999999999999999.99 | 0 | ERROR: Column emp_sal value not valid : 999999999999999.99 |

Getting above error for emp_sal data type validation for which length is decimal(17,2).
I think lambda function of emp_sal is using avg_sal data type decimal(19,6) instead of decimal(17,2) and which is because of v_dec_fun1 which is same variable used for emp_sal & avg_sal. Is there any way of using same variable in lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and its working fine. I changed the avg value to below

```
   (1,"999999999999999.99","1000"),
   (2,"999999999999999.99","2000")
```

In your scenario, when you are specifying the digit here, it actually considers the range of digits rather than the exact value

```
v_dec_prec='2'
v_dec_scale='0'
v_dec_fun1='decimal('+v_dec_prec+','+v_dec_scale+')'
print(v_dec_fun1)
(dd_key,dd_val) = ("avg_sal",lambda c: f.col(c).cast(v_dec_fun1))
dd_file_col_type[dd_key] = dd_val
```

[image]